# Get all loaded shared libraries by a process

Tags: c, linux-kernel, kernel-module

How can i get all loaded shared libraries by a process (sth similar to ltd) from task_struct ?

I am trying to do this by explore 'files' field from task_struct but i am failed on this.

I am using Linux ubuntu 3.2.0-31-generic x86_64

//edit

solve of above problem thanks to [R..](https://stackoverflow.com/users/379897/r)
it print more than should but i thing it is still helpful

```
struct task_struct *p;
struct file*  f;
struct mm_struct* mm;
struct vm_area_struct* vm_area;

rcu_read_lock();

for_each_process(p) {
    printk(KERN_WARNING "Pid: %d %d", p->pid, atomic_read(&p->files->count));
    mm = get_task_mm(p);
    if (mm == 0)
        continue;
    vm_area = mm->mmap;
    while (vm_area != 0){
        f = vm_area->vm_file;
        if (f != 0){
            printk(KERN_WARNING "file %s", f->f_path.dentry->d_iname);
        } else {
            printk(KERN_WARNING "file null");
        }
        vm_area = vm_area->vm_next;
    }
}
rcu_read_unlock();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The kernel has no idea of loaded shared libraries, only memory mappings. You can get those from the vma list, and you can also see them from userspace in `/proc/$pid/maps`. On the other hand, an application can get a list of its own shared libraries via `dl_iterate_phdr`.